# Delete Salesforce Standard force.com pages and classes

Tags: administration, bestpractice

We are in the process of cleaning up our code (updating to latest versions, removing unnecessary code....) and we found many force.com standard pages and classes that we are not using. Can any one please suggest what are the best practices regarding handling these either delete them or update them to latest versions and keep them since we are not close to apex usage limits ?

^^Edit

I am trying to delete/update the version for standard apex classes and pages like "SiteRegisterController", "SiteLoginController", "SiteRegister"....

Thank you !

Comment: Please add more information to your question. You cannot delete elements of the core Salesforce application; what specific metadata are you trying to remove?

Comment: I am trying to delete/update the version for standard apex classes and pages like "SiteRegisterController", "SiteLoginController", "SiteRegister"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure you're not using them, feel free to delete them if you want to. Salesforce will recreate them later if you need them.

It's easier to keep a clean house with regular maintenance than to wait until you *need* to clean up before you do so.

It's called "technical debt", and accumulating a little debt is fine, but if you get too much, it's hard to get caught up.

As long as you keep your debt reasonable, it's easy to keep on top of it.